# How to export the query output to csv in Hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I want to save the query output in the .csv file using Hive. I am using following command in the hadoop command line.

```
hive -e "SELECT t4 AS sev, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Samplelogs WHERE t4 LIKE '[%' GROUP BY t4" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  >> outputfile.csv
```

But it is producing the Parsing error "Cannot recognise symbol near **'hive' '-' 'e'**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this command has to be executed from a shell and not hadoop command line as `hive` is a binary executable. In addition, you can use the `insert overwrite directory` command described here  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and this is how I was able to address it.

Step 1 - Loaded the data from hive table into another table as follows

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestHiveTableCSV;
>   CREATE TABLE TestHiveTableCSV ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' AS
>   SELECT Column List FROM TestHiveTable;

Step 2 - Copied the blob from hive warehouse to the new location with appropriate extension

> Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy 
>   `-DestContext $destContext`
>   -SrcContainer "Source Container" 
>   `-SrcBlob "hive/warehouse/TestHiveTableCSV/000000_0"`
>   -DestContainer "Destination Container" `
>   -DestBlob "CSV/TestHiveTable.csv"

Hope this helps!